# Photo Library Image URL "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000007&ext=JPG" is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I want to get Image URL from Photo gallery of iPad.

When I am trying to get **UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL** from info of Image Piicker
I am getting URL as   :

```
 assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000007&ext=JPG
```

Because I want to get Image Metadata `(image height,width and size in MB)` without loading into memory.

I tried below code:

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
    {
        NSURL *mediaURL;
        mediaURL=(NSURL*)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSURL *imageFileURL = (NSURL*)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

        NSLog(@" referenURL %@  mediaURL %@" ,imageFileURL,mediaURL);

        //We can get Image property from imagepath.
        //NSURL *imageFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",_directoryPath,roomImageNames[i]]];
        CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)imageFileURL, NULL);
        NSDictionary *properties = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, NULL);

        CGFloat height = [[properties objectForKey:@"PixelHeight"] floatValue];
        CGFloat width = [[properties objectForKey:@"PixelWidth"] floatValue];
        NSLog(@"height %f  width  %f",height ,width);
}
```

I am getting image height and width as 0.0

Let me know if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: If is not saved you have no url yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After iOS8, you should use `Photos.framework` to access system photos library.

The single photo model is a `PHAsset` instance object. It has `pixelWidth` and `pixelHeight` properties which storaged current photo's size info. Throught these infomations, you can calculate its memory size.

Answer (score 1):

These functions allow you to access certain image metadata without having to load the actual pixel data into memory. For example, getting the pixel dimensions works like this (make sure to include the **ImageIO.framework** in your target):

`#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>`

```
NSURL *imageFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:...];
CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)imageFileURL, NULL);
if (imageSource == NULL) {
    // Error loading image
    ...
    return;
}

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], (NSString *)kCGImageSourceShouldCache,
                         nil];
CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)options);
if (imageProperties) {
    NSNumber *width = (NSNumber *)CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth);
    NSNumber *height = (NSNumber *)CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight);
    NSLog(@"Image dimensions: %@ x %@ px", width, height);
    CFRelease(imageProperties);
}
CFRelease(imageSource);
```

For more details: [Accessing Image Properties Without Loading the Image Into Memory](https://oleb.net/blog/2011/09/accessing-image-properties-without-loading-the-image-into-memory/)